# Get SUM of matched records and then UPDATE those records using JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Firstly, I want to get SUM of the matched records according to some parameters, for which I have written the below query -

```
@Query(value = "select sum(charges) from usage_logs where X=:x and Y=:y and Z=:z  and status=1", nativeQuery = true)
Double getCharges(@Param("x")String x,@Param("y") String y,@Param("z") String z);
```

At the same time I want to update the status to **"0"** of the matched records(Immediately after for which the charges are calculated).

So, is there any optimised way to update the records after getting the SUM or I need to fetch the **ids** of the matched records and update then separately using a batch function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transaction for this. The SQL would be these four statements.

```
START TRANSACTION;
select sum(charges) from usage_logs where X=:x and Y=:y and Z=:z  and status=1 FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE usage_logs SET status=0 where X=:x and Y=:y and Z=:z  and status=1;
COMMIT;
```

The [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) protects your operation from interference by other things happening concurrently on your database. It ensures that both uses of your `WHERE` clause choose precisely the same rows. And, if your program logic decides that you don't want to proceed with the update, you can say `ROLLBACK;` in place of `COMMIT;`